# Apply slide toggle effect dynamically on click of all div

Tags: jquery, html, css

When clicking on a specific `li` element - I want to be able to open it's respective `div` element.

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="no-padding pro-list">
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-1 pro">A</a>
        <div class="proc-description panel-1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                    Lorem ipsum doner inut.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-2 pro">B</a>
        <div class="proc-description panel-2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                    Lorem ipsum doner inut.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-3 pro">C</a>
        <div class="proc-description panel-3">
            <p>a</p>
            <p>b</p>
            <p>c</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-4 pro">D</a>
        <div class="proc-description panel-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                    Lorem ipsum doner inut.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-5 pro">E</a>
        <div class="proc-description panel-5">
            Hello world! Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                    Lorem ipsum doner inut.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-6 pro">F</a>
        <div class="proc-description panel-6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                    Lorem ipsum doner inut.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-7 pro">G</a>
        <div class="proc-description panel-7">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                    Lorem ipsum doner inut.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-8 pro">H</a>
        <div class="proc-description panel-8">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                    Lorem ipsum doner inut.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="proc-9 ">I</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="proc-10 ">J</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="proc-11 ">K</a></li>
</ul>
```

It works fine when I add this script:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        jQuery(".pro-2").click(function () {
            jQuery(".panel-2").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

However I want to make it dynamic. Instead of making so many functions for each **a class and div class**, I want to create 1 function that can toggle all `li` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this problem is here:

```
<script> 
       jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            jQuery("ul.pro-list a.pro").click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
                jQuery(this).next('div').slideToggle("slow");
           });

</script>
```

where **e is event**,  and **preventDefault()** prevents you from anchor links, which means it doesn't redirects to the 'a links' and if it doesn't redirects to a link our toggle effect works.

Comment: But it didn't in my case, so I used this

Comment: I'm sorry, if you marked it as negative, but this only solved my prolem and it is the answer to my question.

Comment: Why should I do that? Approval is up to you. my answer did not worked, you did no t approve plain and simple

Comment: **You did not knew the solution to your problem and now you answer is the answer. And you are calling me cheap**

Comment: Since I got the solution I declare it as the answer. Its upto anyone to believe it or not. **Sorry, to be harsh I thought you might have done it.**

Answer (score 8):

You should bind event with a common class and then use traversal method to identify element to work on.

You can use already added `pro` class added to `anchor` and `proc-description` added to div.

*Use*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery("a.pro").click(function(){
       jQuery(this).next(".proc-description").slideToggle("slow");
   return false; 
  });            
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery("a.pro").click(function(){
       jQuery(this).next(".proc-description").slideToggle("slow");
      
   });            
});
```

```css
.proc-description {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-padding pro-list">
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-1 pro">A</a>

        <div class="proc-description panel-1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut. Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-2 pro">B</a>

        <div class="proc-description panel-2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut. Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-3 pro">C</a>

        <div class="proc-description panel-3">
            <p>a</p>
            <p>b</p>
            <p>c</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-4 pro">D</a>

        <div class="proc-description panel-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut. Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-5 pro">E</a>

        <div class="proc-description panel-5">Hello world! Lorem ipsum doner inut.
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut. Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-6 pro">F</a>

        <div class="proc-description panel-6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut. Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-7 pro">G</a>

        <div class="proc-description panel-7">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut. Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="pro-8 pro">H</a>

        <div class="proc-description panel-8">
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut. Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="proc-9 ">I</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="proc-10 ">J</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="proc-11 ">K</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ohh Yes, I forgot to mention the _css and js file_ included. And yes I added those classes for this purpose only.
If the script doesn't works for the different classes, it might work for the same class.
**Sorry, but this code doesn't works. Rather it jumps to the link given in href.**

Comment: I checked it by removing href as well, and it do not work using that as well

Comment: @Nehal use return false at end

Comment: I got the answer @Satpal, you should check it. And thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Another Method if you want:-

```
<ul class="no-padding pro-list">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pro-1 pro" onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">A</a>
    <div class="proc-description panel-1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)"class="pro-2 pro" onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">B</a>
    <div class="proc-description panel-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pro-3 pro" onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">C</a>
    <div class="proc-description panel-3">
        <p>a</p>
        <p>b</p>
        <p>c</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pro-4 pro" onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">D</a>
    <div class="proc-description panel-4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pro-5 pro" onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">E</a>
    <div class="proc-description panel-5">
        Hello world! Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                    <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pro-6 pro" onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">F</a>
    <div class="proc-description panel-6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pro-7 pro" onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">G</a>
    <div class="proc-description panel-7">
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pro-8 pro" onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">H</a>
    <div class="proc-description panel-8">
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doner inut.</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum doner inut.
                Lorem ipsum doner inut.
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="proc-9 " onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">I</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="proc-10 " onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">J</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="proc-11 " onclick="$(this).parent().find('.proc-description').toggle();">K</a></li>
```

```
<style>
.proc-description{
    display: none;
}
```